# Is it necessary to have downtime if you want to delete a users spool files

Tags: ibm-midrange

We have a production system(as400) running 24/7 and one of our systems for a specified user is generating allot of spool files.

The issue has been resolved but we are stuck with allot of spoolfiles that I want to delete. Using the following command on the green screen.

```
DLTSPLF FILE(*SELECT) SELECT(THE USER)
```

My question is will we need downtime if I want to run the command or can I do it while the users are busy?

Comment: Are you getting an error? You should be able to delete spool files at any time.

Comment: No, wont get an error just wanted to know if it will have an impact on the live system for instance locking something, or if the users programs try to store a spool file and I am busy deleting it will it be a problem?

Comment: Spool files are meant for output, the only impact is if the user wanted to print it out. We delete old spool files daily.

Comment: Will accept you answer

Comment: Be aware that DLTSPLF may delete spooled files that are in OPN status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spool files are meant for output, the only impact is if the user wanted to print it out. We delete old spool files daily.

Comment: I strongly agree that there's little point in generating spooled printer files if they're not to be printed. Also, it should always be possible to regenerate, so little need to keep on a queue for months. I set up extra queues, one per day-of-week. Spooled files are aged, and when a week old are moved to the queue for that day. That day's queue is cleared at start of day, so maximum age results as two weeks.